# Symfony2 KnpPaginator bundle Get Data from multiple entities and render in one Grid/Pagination

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, knpmenubundle, knppaginatorbundle

I have a scenario where a role called MIS_Data_Entry. The Job of role is to input data in muliple entites. but it's key field `verified is set to false'. The MIS_Manager recieves these data and either accept it or reject. Now for MIS_Data_Entry. I have to show him all the data from multiple entities into one page/Grid.

```
  public function indexAction()
    {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $userId = $user->getId();
            $boards = $em->getRepository('PNCMISDashboardBundle:ExaminationBoards')->findBoardToVerified($userId);
            $institutes = $em->getRepository('PNCInstitutesBundle:Institutes')->findInstituteToVerified($userId);


            return $this->render('PNCMISDashboardBundle:Outbox:index.html.twig', array(
                'boards'=> $boards,
                'institutes'=>$institutes,
            ));


    }
```

New to symfony, don't understand how can i join these two results into one and renders the pageination.

on pagination i will only show Entity Name, Subject, Created on , Statas[verfied  or not], show detail.
on clicking show details pop up model will dispaly the detail resut of every row.
How can i do this.

**UPDATE**

> Most of these entities are not related to each other and some are. But
>   the thing is that they all have createdby key that is associated with
>   the user. So i need to get all these record from multiple tables and
>   combined them to show in one pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use Symfony's pagination component/KnpPaginatorBundle?
Do boards and institutes have a relation?
If so, you need to give it a query object using [Doctrine Query Builder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).
It shouldn't be a problem if you understand SQL.

Otherwise, tell us more about your problem. What these entities represent, how are they related?

Comment: Yes, because there will be hundreds of records and i have to use `KnpPaginatorBundle`